# How to print a ; symbol using CMake command?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake

I am building Boost as an `ExternalProject` under CMake. I want to cross compile for arm. To do this, I am trying to write `using gcc : arm : arm-linux-gnueabi ;` to user-config.jam before the build step.

However, it seems to *refuse* to print a `;` symbol. I can only assume that this is due to some sort of mangling by CMake passing the command to the shell. I tried to edit project-config.jam inline using `sed`, but had the same result. Now I'm trying to `echo` the line to user-config.jam.

Here is my ExternalProject command in CMakeLists.txt:

```
ExternalProject_Add(Boost
    URL https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost/1.59.0/boost_1_59_0.tar.gz
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/downloads/boost_1_59_0
    BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/downloads/boost_1_59_0
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    PATCH_COMMAND ""

    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./bootstrap.sh --prefix="${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/boost_1_59_0" --without-icu
    COMMAND echo using gcc : arm : arm-linux-gnueabi > ./user-config.jam
    COMMAND echo ; >> ./user-config.jam
    BUILD_COMMAND "./b2"
    INSTALL_COMMAND ./b2 install toolset=gcc-arm --prefix=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/boost
    INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/boost
)
```

The verbose CMake prints:

```
cd /home/matthew/Desktop/arm/downloads/boost_1_59_0 && echo using gcc : arm : arm-linux-gnueabi > ./user-config.jam
cd /home/matthew/Desktop/arm/downloads/boost_1_59_0 && echo >> ./user-config.jam
```

You can see that it prints the using ... gnueabi line fine to user-config.jam. However, it seems to treat `;` as an null character. It does the same thing when I use single and double quotes around the `;` character as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semicolon is the list delimiter for cmake. CMake 2.8.11 and greater have a special $ token:

```
COMMAND echo $<SEMICOLON> >> ./user-config.jam
```

As a side-note, you can make your cmake configuration more platform independent by using the `cmake -E <command>`:

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo ...
```

It probably doesn't matter for echo, for other functionallity (creating/removing directories) it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: I should have specified, quotes (single and double) don't help.

Comment: does the verbose output look different from what you posted with quotes?

Comment: COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo ";" >> ./user-config.jam    and now it prints as      cd /home/matthew/Desktop/arm/downloads/boost_1_59_0 && /usr/bin/cmake -E echo >> ./user-config.jam

Comment: cmake uses ; as a list delimiter. Try escaping with backslash. There's also a special $<SEMICOLON> token in cmake >= 2.8.11

Comment: In a more concise test, it looks like a single backslash inside the quote makes the semicolon print.

Comment: $<SEMICOLON> did the trick! Please update your answer and I'll mark it accepted. Thank you!

Comment: No, it didn't work for me. Only the $<SEMICOLON> var did